# Sublists of a list using list comprehension

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

That simple. I want to generate all sublists of a list using list comprehension.

i.e: getSublist [1,2,3] is [[1], [2], [3], [1,2], [1,3], [2, 3], [1,2,3]]

Thanks

Comment: Do you really want to exclude the empty list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is already implemented as `Data.List.subsequences`, but if you want to define it yourself (for learning purposes), you can do it like this:

You can't do it with only list comprehensions, but with some recursion it looks like this:

```
sublists [] = [[]]
sublists (x:xs) = [x:sublist | sublist <- sublists xs] ++ sublists xs
```

Read: The only sublist of the empty list is the empty list. The sublists of `x:xs` (i.e. the list with the head `x` and the tail `xs`) are all of the sublists of `xs` as well as each of the sublists of `xs` with `x` prepended to them.

Comment: Thanks, it's the same idea I had but purely recursive:
subList (x:xs) = (subList xs) ++ (map (\xs -> x:xs) (subList xs))

Comment: atks: Note that you DO need the base case of the recursion. This is not about being recursive or not, it is about `subList` the way you wrote it here only being defined for a non-empty list — only for one of two constructors as it were.

Comment: I like `sublists = filterM $ const [False, True]`

Comment: Mikael, thanks for the point, but I was aware of that. I just omitted in the post because posting in comments is awful. :)