# How can I write a function in Haskell that takes a list of Ints and returns all the contiguous sublists of that list?

Tags: list, haskell

The function needs to take an ordered list of integer elements and return all the combinations of adjacent elements in the original list. e.g `[1,2,3]` would return `[[1,2,3],[1],[1,2],[2],[2,3],[3]]`.

Note that `[1,3]` should not be included, as `1` and `3` are not adjacent in the original list.

Comment: yes [1,3] is forgotten, as is []

Comment: If it's homework, please tag it as such in the future :)

Comment: Okay, shall do in future thanks.

Comment: Just a note to say that this isn't an **exact** duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149109 . To paraphrase a helpful flag: *What is asked is not implemented by `Data.List.subsequences`, as incorrectly answered by some other people: `subsequences` returns all subsequences, but the submitter asks for contiguous subsequences.*

Answer (score 6):

Apart from the fact that `inits` and `tails` aren't found in `Prelude`, you can define your function as such:

```
yourFunction :: [a] -> [[a]]
yourFunction = filter (not . null) . concat . map inits . tails
```

This is what it does, step by step:

- `tails` gives all versions of a list with zero or more starting elements removed: `tails [1,2,3] == [[1,2,3],[2,3],[3],[]]`
- `map inits` applies `inits` to every list given by `tails`, and does exactly the opposite: it gives all versions of a list with zero or more ending elements removed: `inits [1,2,3] == [[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]`
- I hope you already know `concat`: it applies `(++)` where you see `(:)` in a list: `concat [[1,2],[3],[],[4]] == [1,2,3,4]`. You need this, because after `map inits . tails`, you end up with a list of lists of lists, while you want a list of lists.
- `filter (not . null)` removes the empty lists from the result. There will be more than one (unless you use the function on the empty list).

You could also use `concatMap inits` instead of `concat . map inits`, which does exactly the same thing. It usually also performs better.

---

Edit: you can define this with `Prelude`-only functions as such:

```
yourFunction = concatMap inits . tails
    where inits = takeWhile (not . null) . iterate init
          tails = takeWhile (not . null) . iterate tail
```

Comment: `concatMap (tail . inits) . tails` if you want to avoid the `filter`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand the problem alot more.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you need consecutive and non empty answers (as you've noticed in comment).

At first, let's define a simple sublist function.

```
sublist' [] = [[]]
sublist' (x:xs) = sublist' xs ++ map (x:) (sublist' xs)
```

It returns all sublists with empty and non-consecutive lists. So we need to filtering elements of that list. Something like `sublists = (filter consecutive) . filter (/= []) . sublist'`

To check list for it's consecution we need to get pairs of neighbors (`compactByN 2`) and check them.

```
compactByN :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
compactByN _ [] = [[]]
compactByN n list | length list == n = [list]
compactByN n list@(x:xs)= take n list : compactByN n xs
```

And finally

```
consecutive :: [Int] -> Bool
consecutive [_] = True
consecutive x = all (\[x,y] -> (x + 1 == y)) $ compact_by_n 2 x
```

And we have

```
λ> sublists [1,2,3]
[[3],[2],[2,3],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

Done. http://hpaste.org/53965

Answer (score 0):

Unless, I'm mistaken, you're just asking for the superset of the numbers.

The code is fairly self explanatory - our superset is recursively built by building the superset of the tail twice, once with our current head in it, and once without, and then combining them together and with a list containing our head.

```
superset xs = []:(superset' xs) -- remember the empty list
superset' (x:xs) = [x]:(map (x:) (superset' xs)) ++ superset' xs
superset' [] = []
```

Comment: As it turns out, this is asking for contiguous sublists, not the power set. I misread it the first time too :)