# Sublists of lists using recursion in scala

Tags: algorithm, list, scala, recursion, stack-overflow

I tried to look for some algorithms to find all of the sub lists of a given list and this is what I found:

> The only sublist of the empty list is the empty list. The sublists of x:xs (i.e. the list with the head x and the tail xs) are all of the sublists of xs as well as each of the sublists of xs with x prepended to them.

taken from [Sublists of a list using list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149109/sublists-of-a-list-using-list-comprehension)

Here is what I implemented:

```
    def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] = occurrences match{
    case List() => List()
    case x::xs => combinations(xs) ::: combinations(x :: xs)

  }
```

This function gives a stack overflow error as I expected however in the example from that question it worked for him. It might've been that I misunderstood the principle he explained? How could I tackle such a problem using recursion? Where was my mistake here?

Where can I look for such an algorithm?

Comment: You have infinite recursion after :::

Comment: @Daenyth Yes. That is correct. Check Kigyo answer. As I can see this algorithm now, it fails for my cases. Do you know a better algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the algorithm according to your stated definition.

For the empty List, return a List with an empty List.

For the other case, use recursion to get all combinations from the `tail` and then additionally combine the `head` with each element from the result (`tailComb`). (`tailComb.map(sub => x :: sub)`).

```
def combinations[A](list: List[A]): List[List[A]] = list match {
  case Nil => List(List.empty[A])
  case x::xs => {
    val tailComb = combinations(xs)
    tailComb ::: tailComb.map(sub => x :: sub)
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the algorithm doesn't work in my cases if this is what it translates to. What better algorithm would you recommend me? ( I don't want code. I just want a name of an algorithm or a link if you could tell me)

Comment: Why does it not work? This is the definition you gave me. What can I recommend when you don't tell me what you want? Give an example.

Comment: Sublists of lists using recursion in scala as the title states. If you want more clarification: [1,2,3] = [1,2],[1],[2],[3],[2,3] and so on

Comment: combinations([1,2,3]) gives [[], [1], [2], [3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [1,2,3]]. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Hm. My bad. My test was based on a `List[(Char,Int)]` for which it did compile but didn't show all the results. My question wasn't that however so I will mark this as accepted

Comment: Sorry. You can try it with a new question, but you should put more detail to it, so we can really be of help.